# How to store pushnotification in coredata when app is terminated or killed?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to store push notification(FCM) in **coredata** when app is terminated or killed. its does not working. But when app is background state is storing perfectly.also when i click the notification its stored perfectly. But i can't stored in **coredata** killed state.

i am using **FCM** notifications

1. Is that possible notification store **coredata** in iOS when app is killed state?
2. Any solution for storing **coredata** when app is killed.

Comment: When the app is killed it cannot receive push notifications. Push notifications are not guaranteed to be delivered anyway. When your app starts it should pull any updates from the server

Comment: Thanks for reply. yes its one way for retrieving and store. We are already discuss with my team. Any other possible way to store the notifications in core data?. Thank a lot for gave a reply

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`UNNotificationServiceExtension`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension). This is intended to use as an interceptor to modify the content of incoming notifications before presented to the user. However, you can use this interceptor to just save the notification to CoreData. Be sure to set the `mutable-content` to `1` on your notification data payload. Only these would be intercepted.

FCM supports this `mutable-content` and I do something very similar in one of my project to acknowledge my backend that the user receiving notification and it works flawlessly.

```
import UserNotifications

class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {
    
    var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
    var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?
    
    override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest,
                             withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
        self.contentHandler = contentHandler
        bestAttemptContent = request.content.mutableCopy()
        
        // TODO
        // Save the notification to core data
        
        contentHandler(request.content)
    }
    
    override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
        if let contentHandler = contentHandler,
           let bestAttemptContent =  bestAttemptContent {
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply bro. thanks i will check that and tell u.

I have one doubt : if backend add the mutable content, we can stored data in locally right via your extension. R u from tamilnadu?

Comment: Hi i am trying this one. unable to store in coredata. Can u please explain this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your payload its working. My side i have changed payload, working perfectly.

[Background modes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vINzv.png). Check your background modes.

Change your Payload :

```
  {
     "to": "Device GCM Id",
     "content_available": true,
     "mutable_content": true,
     "notification":
      {
        "body":"Your Notification message",
        "sound": "default",
        "title":"Your App tittle"
     }
  }
```

Appdelegate :

```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
 {
       // Save pushnotification data to core data
 }
```

This is method should save in coredata when your app killed.My side 100% working.